# How to get alerts for inputed name length of characters - javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

Hello im trying to do a simple script here when i enter name in input field, i want to get certain alerts for example:
 - if name is > 20 characters alert = "name is bigger than 20"
 - if name is between 12 and 20 alert = exact number of chars of the name that was inputed
 - if name is bigger than 2 chars and bigger or equal than 20 = alert that name
 this was just an example of what im trying to do, but im just noob at this point im only 1 month into javascript(html and css) so if anyone can point me in the right direction i would appreciate.

Ok, so far i have this:

```
<form name="myForm" id="form2" onsubmit="return validate()">
Input name: <input type="text" name = "myName" id="t" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>


    function validate() {

    if(document.myForm.myName.value.length>20){
    alert("your name is too big");
     submitFlag=false;   // im not sure what this line does //
    } else if(document.myForm.myName.value.length=12-20){
         alert("your name is" + document.myForm.myName.value.length + " chars");

             } else if(document.myForm.myName.value.length=0){
        alert("input name")

      }else{
      alert("ok e")
    }
        return submitFlag;

}
```

THe if statements are workin only if i have two, im getting only the first 2 alerts, so i would like to input more else if statements and to get alerts for them also, i tried to put some more myself, but the dont work, im only getting the first two.

Comment: Please try learning the language and understanding what your code does before pasting a code sample from somewhere and asking SO to help you get it working.

Comment: Sergey Narozhnyy, dfsq, Ashish Kumar, thank you guys very much for your input and help, so ill just pick an answer so this question can be closed .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending what @dfsq have said,.. you try to get:

> if name is between 12 and 20

that means smth like:

```
document.myForm.myName.value.length > 12 && document.myForm.myName.value.length <= 20
```

And make your code more simple and readable. And don't forget to return false (your submitFlag):

```
function validate() {
  var len = document.myForm.myName.value.length;
  if (len > 20)
  {
     alert("your name is too big");
  }
  else if (len > 12 && len <= 20)
  {
     alert("your name is" + len + " chars");
  }
  else if (len == 0)
  {
     alert("input name");
  }
  else
  {
     //in fact it would alert when name between 0 and 12        
     alert("ok e");
  }
 return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a difference between operators. `=` is an assignment, `==` and `===` are comparison operators. You need latter:

```
document.myForm.myName.value.length == 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but still not getting anything after the first "else if" statement even with ==

Comment: Take a look at this example of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/8tft0ujf/ That's probably how it should be. Since you are using `else-if` blocks you are going to get only one alert..

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

```
function validate() {
    var charLength = document.myForm.myName.value.length,
        submitFlag = false; // This flag would be used further to stop the use going ahead from this particular validation

    if (charLength > 20) {
        // length more than 20
        alert("your name is too big");
    } else if (charLength <= 20 && charLength > 12) {
        // length between 20 and 12
        alert("your name is" + charLength + " chars");
    } else if (charLength == 0) {
        // If no input there
        alert("enter name");
    } else {
        // Otherwise in success condition
        alert("ok e");
        submitFlag = true;
    }

    return submitFlag;
}
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fcwbkkd7/